# Suppress or Customize Intro Message in Fish Shell

Tags: fish

Is it possible to remove the intro message in fish shell:

> Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
>
> Type help for instructions on how to use fish

Answer (score 274, accepted):

Found that the greeting message is set in fishd.Machine.local. To override the following to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
set fish_greeting
```

Comment: Alternatively, set it permanently for this machine with `set -U fish_greeting ""`.

Comment: `set fish_greeting` is from the docs how you can remove it http://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#faq-greeting

Comment: A little nuance, but to have no greeting at all, just invoke the suggested `set` command.

Comment: Better yet `set -U fish_greeting ""`

Comment: This command (`set fish_greeting`) seemed to have no effect on fish 3.3.1, but `set -U fish_greeting ""` worked.

Answer (score 200):

Kevin's answer works fine for static text. If you need an interactive welcome message, such as mine involving the *fortune* command, you can do

```
function fish_greeting
```

Create your `fish_greeting` function. I just have

```
function fish_greeting
    fortune
end
```

and save it with

```
funcsave fish_greeting
```

Comment: Good tip. I'm using `fortune -a` so I can get the offensive stuff too.

Comment: Don't forget to install `fortune`

Answer (score 52):

> Warning: No longer works since fish 2.4.0—see [Kevin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13995944/2903889) answer for the correct contemporary solution.

If there is no environment variable named "fish_greeting", then nothing will be printed. By default, there is a fish_greeting variable. You can erase this:

```
set --erase fish_greeting
```

Comment: yes, once the variable is deleted it won't be re-created.

Comment: I think this worked once, but it doesn't anymore; now it seems you need to [set the variable to an empty string](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#faq-greeting).

Answer (score 16):

```
> set --universal fish_greeting
```

Answer (score 10):

Create your fish_greeting function. I just have

```
function fish_greeting                                             13:23:39
    echo 'Hello'
end
```

and save it with

```
funcsave fish_greeting
```

Answer (score 8):

Read the official document please.

http://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#faq-greeting

short answer: `set -e fish_greeting`

Comment: Note, the FAQs now say to use `set -U fish_greeting` or `set -g fish_greeting`

Answer (score 8):

Add `set fish_greeting` to your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file.

This is answered in [the Fish FAQ](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html):

> **How do I run a command every login? What's fish's equivalent to .bashrc?**
>
> Edit the file `~/.config/fish/config.fish`, creating it if it does not exist (Note the leading period).
>
> **How do I change the greeting message?**
>
> Change the value of the variable `fish_greeting` or create a `fish_greeting` function. For example, to remove the greeting use:
>
> ```
> set fish_greeting
> ```

Answer (score 6):

This is a kind of `silly` answer. You can create a `fish_greeting.fish` empty file in `~/.config/fish/functions` folder and this will remove the greeting message.

That can be done by

```
$ touch ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_greeting.fish
```

Or

```
$ function fish_greeting.fish
end

$ funcsave fish_greeting.fish
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `$ function fish_greeting` so we don't end up with a file called `fish_greeting.fish.fish`?

Answer (score 5):

Change the value of the variable `fish_greeting` or create a `fish_greeting` function. For example, to remove the greeting use:

```
set -U fish_greeting
```

Or if you prefer not to use a universal variable, use:

```
set -g fish_greeting
```

**Make sure to add space after fish_greeting if you need to disable the greeting**

Answer (score 4):

You could also display random pokemon as fish greeting after installing this [script](https://github.com/ph04/pokemon-icat) here. Open your terminal and type in:

```
function fish_greeting
    $HOME/.pokemon-icat/pokemon-icat.sh
end
```

And save the function for future fish greetings

```
funcsave fish_greeting
```

I just love it to open a terminal and the first thing that pops up is a pokemon. Even more satisfying if its a legend one :)