# Remove Fish shell error message in greetings

Tags: ubuntu, config, gnome, fish, gnome-terminal

I wanted to remove Fish shell greetings. As I was searching for the solution, I went to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995857/suppress-or-customize-intro-message-in-fish-shell#19291140) saw a technique where I can minimize default welcome script to the new one. And I did this on my terminal:

```
pranav@exam ~> function fish_greeting
                   StackOverflow
               end
pranav@exam ~> funcsave fish_greeting
```

This is accepted & highly voted answer. I wonder why it didn't work for me. Because launching the terminal again will show this big mess above the user input:

```
~/.config/fish/functions/fish_greeting.fish (line 2): 
StackOverflow
^
in function 'fish_greeting'
    called on line 126 of file /usr/share/fish/functions/__fish_config_interactive.fish
in function '__fish_config_interactive'
    called on line 170 of file /usr/share/fish/config.fish
in function '__fish_on_interactive'
in event handler: handler for generic event “fish_prompt”
pranav@exam ~>
```

So I wanted to remove it greetings altogether by when I found [this command in the FAQ page of Fish](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#faq-greeting):

```
pranav@exam ~> set fish_greeting
```

Now, the problem is this doesn't work. I've relaunched the terminal, stopped the **GDM**, and restart the GDM since I use **Wayland** display server, tried to logout & login and even restarted my computer but none of them worked. Because I can still see the error message whenever I launch the terminal. I use **Ubuntu 20.04** with pranav@exam ~>. If u are the fish shell expert, help the noob student who has just started to use this amazing shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your fish_greeting function tries to execute a command named "StackOverflow" that doesn't exist. The original answer suggested using the "fortune" command, which is an actual thing you might have installed.

If you have both a function and a variable named "fish_greeting", the function takes precedence, so the solution is to fix the function. Use a command that exists, or none at all:

```
function fish_greeting
end

funcsave fish_greeting
```